# Calculate Profit Price for a given percentage

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

I am trying to work out a formula that given the BuyPrice, FeeRate and ProfitPercentage - will give me the Sell price, given that the FeeRate is charged to buy and sell.

I have been using this question to get the break even formula but I don't know how to extend it to apply a percentage gain.

```
Sell Rate = (Fee + 1) / ((1 / Buy Rate) - (1 / Buy Rate) * Fee)
```